# Manually trigger a suggestion click in SearchView in Android

Tags: android, searchview, search-suggestion

How do I trigger an event that would have been triggered if I would have clicked on one of the suggestions of my SearchView on Android?
I need the system to call the very exact intent along with the passed parameters.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I use the [explicit intent](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) to call the `SearchingActivity` with the required intent filters like:

```
intentSelected.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intentSelected.setData(Uri.parse("item_to_search"));
```